# How to migrate RDS Postgre database from one vpc to another using DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Could someone let me know how to migrate RDS postgre from one vpc to another using DMS? the documents for DMS only talks about using DMS between two differnet database in same vpc or from onpremise to aws..I want to know how to do it for RDS postgre db from one vpc to another..
I dont have schema change.So it should be homogeneous migration..There could be some minor change like patch version change in target RDS postgres DB.However no schema change

Do I need vpc peering for this?

Comment: create a db-parameter-group in the other VPC and update that in your current db.

Comment: If the Source is in different VPC,and target in different VPC,should I have to create any security group to allow the connection for DMS? I tried DMS even in the same VPC as in source DB,but its failing with connection timedout.."Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: [unixODBC]timeout expired"

Comment: Is pushing a backing up to S3 and restoring from there not a possibility ?

Comment: That could be an option..However we have DMS meant for this scenario..So I want to try it out..

Comment: I got this working now..with proper setup of Security groups,Routing table,VPC peeing

Comment: @Rad4 I am also facing the same issue, how did you set up the security groups, routing table and vpc peering. I tried setting those but still facing the same problem maybe I am missing something.